# Linear gradient without color transition

Tags: css

I'm trying to generate a gradient background with `linear-gradient` in CSS. Here's an example codepen https://codepen.io/JSislife/pen/vYxrYEv. As you can see on the bottom right corner there is no transition of colors between orange and white; but the top left is the opposite. How do I make the top left not have a color transition as well?

Comment: like this ?  `background: linear-gradient(135deg, white 15%,#bd6430 15% 70%, white 70%) fixed;` ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Thanks, that worked. Can you explain why there are 2 defined percentages here `#bd6430 15% 70%` ?

Edit: nevermind, I see that you started the color at 15% of the width to match the first color placement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as @G-Cyrillus mentioned in the comments, if you add [color stops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()#gradient_with_multi-position_color_stops) to your [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()) you can create gradient sections that don't fade into eachother but have defined start/stop positions.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, white 0% 15%, #bd6430 15% 70%, white 70%) fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='home'></div>
</body>
</html>
```